# Issue with changed data in a loop: Is it a feature of v-for or a bug of a component or a bug of my code?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I use [vue-smooth-dnd](https://github.com/kutlugsahin/vue-smooth-dnd) and I have a problem with dragging of tracks inside one playlist once tracks are copied from another playlist.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zqv9m19v8l) is the minimal code - just click button to copy tracks from one playlist to another and try to drag any tracks in both playlists. As a result you will see that tracks inside "Slow" playlist are draggable, but in "Electro" they are not.

However if you change the first `:key` from `:key="playlistObj.playlistTitle"` to `:key="Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1"` tracks dragging in the first playlist starts to work.

Is it a feature of v-for or a bug of a component I use or a bug of my code?

Comment: As your code is now, I can just drag and drop within the same playlist. If I try and drag from one playlist to another, the onDrop method is never called. "Draggables can be moved between the containers having the same group names. If not set container will not accept drags from outside." [Source](https://github.com/kutlugsahin/smooth-dnd). I made a fork here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kxqz54k2yo where I added group-name="group" to the Component element.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Hi!. Thank you for the response. I do not need to drag tracks from one playlist to another. I need to copy tracks from"Slow"  playlist to "Electro" and I expect to get draggable tracks in "Electro", but they are not draggable. Once the tracks are copied I can drag just tracks in "Slow" playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the issue of the component and it is already fixed.